# Mount part of a dd image as a truecrypt volume

Tags: linux, truecrypt, dd

I have a dd image of a full drive (as a file) that was using Truecrypt system encryption under windows. I want to mount the main partition from that image using Linux's Truecrypt. I am familiar with dd loopback devices and have the partition offset, but I don't know how I can mount it like this because I need to use the truecrypt command.

Is there perhaps some way to create a fake device file for the disk image that I can mount from within Truecrypt?

Comment: `/dev/loopxx` doesn't work for Truecrypt?

Comment: Okay I didn't know about losetup before! I have tried using losetup to create a loop device with the specified offset into the file, but truecrypt still doesn't seem to like it: "Partition Device Required"

Comment: I don't think that a "fake device file" is part of the UNIX model - mountpoints are about as transparent as you can get, so no *reasonable* program should really care anyway. How TrueCrypt detects that it's on a loopback, I have no idea, but I think it's trying to prevent brute force attacks on a copied disk image.

Comment: I very much doubt they would build in something like that, any attacker worth his salt would just remove such a limitation from the source code of Truecrypt and try again. Plus it wouldn't be a lot of use to try and brute force AES volumes with decent passphrases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I worked around it by using the dd image in vmware, more details: [blog entry](http://www.mossage.co.uk/2011/07/accessing-backups-of-truecrypted-windows-system-drives-under-linux/)

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Yeah sorry it's been broken for some time, it is now redirected to a summary of the lost article.